# split string on multiple white spaces but not single ones

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a function that splits strings on multiple white spaces but not on single ones.

Example:

```
sample_string = "2012.03.04       check everything      status: OK"
split_string = ["2012.03.04", "check everything", "status: OK"]
```

How do I get from `sample_string` to `split_string` without using ugly for loops?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>> help(re.split)
Help on function split in module re:

split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
    Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
    returning a list containing the resulting substrings.  If
    capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
    groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting
    list.  If maxsplit is nonzero, at most maxsplit splits occur,
    and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
    of the list.

>>> re.split(r'\s{2,}', "2012.03.04       check everything      status: OK")
['2012.03.04', 'check everything', 'status: OK']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) for this. ([test link](https://regex101.com/r/THHyz4/1)).

**Code:**

```
import re

sample_string = "2012.03.04       check everything      status: OK"

print(re.split("\s{2,}", sample_string))
```

**Output:**

```
['2012.03.04', 'check everything', 'status: OK']
```

Answer (score 2):

With [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

sample_string = "2012.03.04       check everything      status: OK"
REGEX = re.compile(r' {2,}')  # Two or more spaces
re.split(REGEX, sample_string)
```

will return you:

`['2012.03.04', 'check everything', 'status:', 'OK']`

Answer (score 2):

Use the re package :

```
import re
re.split(r'\s{2,}', sample_string)
```

Output :

```
['2012.03.04', 'check everything', 'status: OK']
```